# Como deixar os extremos de uma div transparentes?

Tags: html, css

Quero aplicar uma cor na `div` e nas laterais dela ela ir ficando mais clara ate ficar transparente, tem como fazer isso com CSS?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas vc quer que isso ocorra quando?

Comment: sempre vai ser efeito visual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quase certeza que foi feito com `background-image: linear-gradient`

Veja no Snippet:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: url(http://placecage.com/600/500) center no-repeat / cover;
}
div {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    width: 50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, black 10%, black 90%, transparent 100%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>texto aqui</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo você pode utilizar um "linear gradiente"

```
div { background-image: linear-gradient( to right,white, black 50%, 
white ); }
```

Você define uma porcentagem para a cor sólida que no caso ficara no meio e dos lados o clareamento até qual tonalidade você quer. Claro que não precisa ser 50% da div preta, você pode colocar menos se preferir.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Você pode usar `box-shadow` pra aplicar esse efeito:</strike>

Ok, não dá pra fazer com `box-shadow` esse efeito de sombra nas laterais que você deseja.

Mas você pode usar gradientes em CSS, são meio complexos e cada navegador tem uma sintaxe, mas um gerador automático pode facilitar esse trabalho: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```css
.blur-box {
  margin: 32px;
  padding: 10 -20%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+100&0+0,1+15,1+85,0+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 85%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-box">INICIAR</div>
```

Comment: então eu so queria nas bordas laterais.

Comment: Editei a pergunta tinha colocado extremos dava a entender que era todos os lados

Comment: Resposta alterada para satisfazer a alteração na pergunta